# replace string for name of file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I need to replace every instance of the word "Genus" in multiple files for their respective file name.

Tried listing every file name and then using

```
for line in `cat list_ids`; do sed 's/Genus/$line/g' $line; done
```

but it returned "$line" instead of the respective file name

Comment: just a list of file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of single quotes prevented variable expansion. Use double quotes:

```
for line in `cat list_ids`; do sed "s/Genus/$line/g" $line; done
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks!